# Browser cache persists when using Varnish

Tags: browser-cache, varnish, varnish-vcl

I think this seems related to Varnish.

After I log out, user status should change. But it didn't. I have use "CTRL + F5" to force cache refreshing.

So I am little confused. I forced refreshing of the browser cache or Varnish cache.

If Varnish is caching the correct page ( user is not logged in), why didn't the browser display it, instead, it persists with the old page when the user still logged in.

Any clue?

> VCL

```
backend testserver {
   .host = "127.0.0.1";
   .port = "8080";
}

acl purge {
   "localhost";
   "127.0.0.1";
   "192.168.3.0"/24;
}

sub vcl_recv {
   if (req.request == "PURGE") {
           if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                   error 405 "Not allowed.";
           }
           return(lookup);
   }
   remove req.http.X-Forwarded-For;
   set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
   // Remove has_js and Google Analytics cookies
   set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|has_js)=[^;]*","");
   // remove a ";" prefix, if present
   set req.http.Cookie = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

   // remove empty cookies.
   if (req.http.Cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
     unset req.http.Cookie;
   }

   // Skip the Vanish cache for install, update, and cron
   if (req.url ~ "install\.php|update\.php|cron\.php") {
     return (pass);
   }

   # Normalize Accept-Encoding to get better cache coherency
   if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
     # No point in compressing media that is already compressed
     if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg)$") {
       remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
       # MSIE 6 JS bug workaround
     } elsif(req.http.User-Agent ~ "MSIE 6") {
       unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
     } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
       set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
     } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate") {
       set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
     } else {
       # unkown algorithm
       remove req.http.Accept-Encoding;
     }
   }

   # ... other vcl_recv rules here ...
   # Don't serve cached content to logged-in users
   # Don't cache Drupal logged-in user sessions
   # LOGGED_IN is the cookie that earlier version of Pressflow sets
   # VARNISH is the cookie which the varnish.module sets
   if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(VARNISH|DRUPAL_UID|LOGGED_IN)") {
     return (pass);
   }

   // Let's have a little grace
   // When backend cannot generate refreshed content
   // this time will allow expired content to stay longer in grace
   set req.grace = 0s;

   if (req.http.host ~ "^www.test.com") {
           set req.backend = testserver;
           if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
                   return(pipe);
           }
           else {
                   return(lookup);
           }
   }elsif (req.http.host ~ "^www.test2.com") {
           set req.backend = testserver;
           if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
                   return(pipe);
           }
           else {
                   return(lookup);
           }
   }
   else {
           error 404 "test Cache Server IS Out of Order";
           return(lookup);
   }

   # Drupal js/css doesn't need cookies, cache them
   if (req.url ~ "^/modules/.*\.(js|css)\?") {
           unset req.http.Cookie;
   }

   ## Pass cron jobs and server-status
   if (req.url ~ "cron.php") {
           return (pass);
   }
   if (req.url ~ ".*/server-status$") {
           return (pass);
   } 
}


sub vcl_hit {
   if (req.request == "PURGE") {
           set obj.ttl = 0s;
           error 200 "Purged.";
   }
}
sub vcl_miss {
   if (req.request == "PURGE") {
           error 404 "Not in cache.";
   } 
}
sub vcl_fetch {
   if (req.url ~ "\.(png|gif|jpg|swf|css|js)$") {
     unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
   }
   #if (beresp.http.Pragma ~ "nocache") {
   #  return(pass);
   #}
   if (req.request == "GET" && req.url ~ "\.(txt|js)$") {
          set beresp.ttl = 3600s;
   }
   else {
         set beresp.ttl = 30d;
   }
 }
sub vcl_error {
  set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
  set obj.http.Retry-After = "5";
  synthetic {"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html><head><title>"} obj.status " " obj.response {"</title></head><body><h1>Error "} obj.status " " obj.response {"</h1><p>"} obj.response {"</p><h3>Guru Meditation:</h3><p>XID: "} req.xid {"</p><hr><p>Varnish cache server</p></body></html>"};
  return (deliver);
}
sub vcl_pipe {
  # http://www.varnish-cache.org/ticket/451
  # This forces every pipe request to be the first one.
  set bereq.http.connection = "close";
}
```

> Headers

**After Log In**

```
Response Headers     view source
Cache-Control   store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Tue, 21 Feb 2012 04:09:09 GMT
Expires Sun, 11 Mar 1984 12:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified   Tue, 21 Feb 2012 04:09:07 GMT
Location    http://www.test.com/frontpage_empty
Server  nginx/1.0.0
Set-Cookie  SESSe3202baa92dbab78a8d1785ee17b05a0=deleted; expires=Mon, 21-Feb-2011 04:09:08 GMT; path=/ SESSe3202baa92dbab78a8d1785ee17b05a0=67d001b0720c9f5a74e5b671fae74d76; expires=Fri, 09-Mar-2012 12:49:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.test.com LOGGED_IN=Y; expires=Fri, 09-Mar-2012 12:49:07 GMT; path=/
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.17
Request Headers      view source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Authorization   Basic amFtZXM6MTIzMTIz
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  OAID=e171ed7b31967c95a09c70646433d7b1; has_js=1; SESSe3202baa92dbab78a8d1785ee17b05a0=054b6fa52ce9009198a2160800d04456; __utma=256091342.2121990614.1327109315.1329792135.1329797585.41; __utmz=256091342.1327109315.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); OAID=e171ed7b31967c95a09c70646433d7b1; SESSa395c7767e83fe1b8cd4bf8229e072c3=2bfb1adba208cf29bf17921ce9946bd5; has_js=1; __utmc=256091342; __utmb=256091342.1.10.1329797585
Host    www.test.com
Referer http://www.test.com/user/login?destination=frontpage_empty
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
Response Headers From Cache
Cache-Control   store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Tue, 21 Feb 2012 04:09:09 GMT
Expires Sun, 11 Mar 1984 12:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified   Tue, 21 Feb 2012 04:09:07 GMT
Location    http://www.test.com/frontpage_empty
Server  nginx/1.0.0
Set-Cookie  SESSe3202baa92dbab78a8d1785ee17b05a0=deleted; expires=Mon, 21-Feb-2011 04:09:08 GMT; path=/ SESSe3202baa92dbab78a8d1785ee17b05a0=67d001b0720c9f5a74e5b671fae74d76; expires=Fri, 09-Mar-2012 12:49:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.test.com LOGGED_IN=Y; expires=Fri, 09-Mar-2012 12:49:07 GMT; path=/
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.17
Request Headers From Upload Stream
Content-Length  61
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

**After log out**

```
Response Headers    view source
Cache-Control   store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Date    Tue, 21 Feb 2012 09:10:29 GMT
Expires Sun, 11 Mar 1984 12:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified   Tue, 21 Feb 2012 09:10:27 GMT
Location    http://www.test.com/
Server  nginx/1.0.0
Set-Cookie  LOGGED_IN=deleted; expires=Mon, 21-Feb-2011 09:10:28 GMT; path=/
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.17
Request Headers     view source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Authorization   Basic amFtZXM6MTIzMTIz
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  SESSe3202baa92dbab78a8d1785ee17b05a0=67d001b0720c9f5a74e5b671fae74d76; __utma=256091342.2121990614.1327109315.1329792135.1329797585.41; __utmz=256091342.1327109315.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); OAID=e171ed7b31967c95a09c70646433d7b1; SESSa395c7767e83fe1b8cd4bf8229e072c3=2bfb1adba208cf29bf17921ce9946bd5; has_js=1; __utmc=256091342; LOGGED_IN=Y
Host    www.test.com
If-Modified-Since   Tue, 21 Feb 2012 03:32:36 GMT
Referer http://www.test.com/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
```

Comment: Could you please post your request and response headers as well as your VCL file ?

Answer (score 0):

What your VCL is currently doing is removing Cookie from the request header and caching all requests. This causes the exact behavior you describe.